# Cannot retrieve the fields from pdf using VBSCRIPT

Tags: pdf, vbscript, acrobat

Have this [PDF](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM0008ENU_2D.pdf) document

```
FileNm = "IMM0008ENU_2D.pdf" 'File location
Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")
Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
   If avDoc.Open(FileNm, "") Then
   Set PDFForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 
   set x=PDFForm.Fields
   wscript.echo "total fields:",x.count
      For Each myField In x
      Wscript.echo myField.Name
      Next
   End If
avDoc.Close (True) 
Set gApp = Nothing
Set avDoc = Nothing
Set PDFForm = Nothing
```

But have result: 0 fields

Please help to retrieve all fields from PDF

Answer (score 2):

[CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/) forms are currently based in the [XFA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA).

From Wikipedia:

> PDF currently supports two different methods for integrating data and
>   PDF forms. Both formats today coexist in PDF specification:[1][5]
>
> AcroForms (also known as Acrobat forms), introduced and included in
>   the PDF 1.2 format specification. Adobe XML Forms Architecture (XFA)
>   forms, introduced in the PDF 1.5 format specification as an optional
>   feature (The XFA specification is not included in the PDF
>   specification, it is only referenced.) Adobe XFA Forms are not
>   compatible with AcroForms. Creating XFA Forms for use in Adobe Reader
>   requires Adobe LiveCycle Forms Designer.

You will need adobe-livecycle instead of Acrobat Professional in order to manipulate this kind of forms programmatically.